# OpenCV high resolution camera capture && display

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl

Two questions (both related):

[q1] I've read through the documentation of OpenCV; it seems no matter what the backing store for a `cv::Mat` is (byte, float, double), the display is always rendered down to 256 levels per channel for the bgr format for display.  What is currently the best method to bypass this limitation?  Can I somehow use OpenGL integration to pipe directly to an opengl display?

[q2] Is it possible to back the display with a higher precision `cv::Mat` and do a dynamic transform on presentation?  Again, OpenGL?  So if I have a Mat that is 1024 x 768, and wish to keep it like this, but declare the window to have a different dimension (512 x 384) so that feeding it the 1024 `cv::Mat` on presentation scales down to 512, but the underlying interface (zoom in particular) retains the 1024 resolution, is this possible?

I suspect the answer is no to both (as possibilities directly addressed by OpenCV) based on their documentation - so the OpenGL integration would be interesting in this respect.  If it makes a difference, I have the OpenCV with Qt involved.  I *don't* want to have to write a bunch of GUI code.  I just want to have the data in OpenCV, call a correct display (compatible with OpenCV) and have the data presented in a somewhat higher-fidelity version than what is currently being done with `imshow`.

Comment: Whether you use OpenGL, QT, MFC, Win32 API, DirectX or whatever, the image will at some point get reduced to three or four 8-bit channels for display (unless you have a nice expensive 16-bit medical imaging monitor and eyesight to match). There's nothing special about OpenCV with respect to what you can do with the image data. Can you explain what the problem is that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Medical imaging on hires displays.  It seems the default of opencv is to render down higher-bit-depth, higher-spatial-depth to a crappy screen format.  I am trying to bypass this using opengl.  Is this the wrong track?

Comment: OpenCV is not an image renderer really. That `imshow` function is just for convenience. If you already have `float` or `double` data in a `cv::Mat` and you know how to build and display a suitable OpenGL texture for your high-res display, just grab the pixels from the `Mat` and do what you would normally do to display it.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to write a bunch of code (specifically basic image ui code already included in opencv) if it wasn't necessary.  ah well. lib can't do everything for everyone, right?  LOL.  thanks for the answer

Comment: Yes, unfortunately supporting high res displays is something of a niche and the general tendency will be for basic 24-bit BGR or 32-bit BGRA output. I'm assuming you're working with 10-bit or 12-bit luminance data.

Comment: Gotchya.  I switched to using opengl to present the data.  Working on using QT to re-add in the gui functionality.